# Linearlayout - map fregmant

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Iam trying to get the Google maps to fill half screen and another half screen I want to fill it with other stuff. But I cant really figure it out how to get it done.

**This what I want is**

[image: Screenshot]
I tried to make it but the problem is I want it shows the same view to other phones too, like wildfire and galaxy s3. i mean screensize. it didnt size it good, it was out of view. I hope someone can help me with it.

**Update XML code **

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50">

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_lv_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_6"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewer_14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:weightSum="5">

<TextView
    android:text="@+id/SomeText"
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Allow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Allow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Allow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

          <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Allow"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deny"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Deny"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="50">

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a layout with half of the screen is a `LinearLayout` on the top half of the screen, and the bottom half is the map, this should work on all screens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the inner `LinearLayout` you can place what ever you want.

Comment: thank you. I was wondering about the image i view in the question, how I can add 5 buttons, 3 textview and the image @ another layout?

Comment: I would put it all in a relative layout. the textView aligned to parent left, the image to right and the button would be placed in a horizontal linear layout with weight 1.0 for all of them and alight this linear layout to parent's bottom.

Comment: I will update my answer, Can u please just look at it and let me know where Iam doing wrong?